# How do I select rows from an Sqlite table exluding ones from a previous query?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I have an Sqlite table having > 25 million rows. I'd selected 1 million rows randomly from this table using the following code:

```
# using sqlite3 code
c = cursor.execute("SELECT * 
FROM reviews_table WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID FROM reviews_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1000000) ")
```

Now, I wish to select another 1 million rows from the table, *excluding* those rows in the previous query. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The first problem I see here is that new data may have been inserted since the last query.  How would you plan on keeping track of this?  Is it not possible for you to get all data at once?

Comment: Is creating a new table sorted by a random key then using offsets not practical for any reason? (eg: `create table sorted as (select * from reviews_table order by random()` - then use that...) - if you've got a PK, you could subset that to be `create table keys as (select pk from reviews_table order by random()` and then join back to reviews_table with offsets for each 1million block

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I'm sorry, I'd forgotten to mention that the database is static. I'm only using it to read data from, and so insertion is a non-issue.

Comment: @JonClements: Thank you, it works! I was initially hesitant to try that as I thought ordering all the rows randomly would take a whole lot of time (ordering 1000000 rows had taken close to 35 seconds, and so I thought I was looking at minutes of runtime). But it executed in well under a minute!

Comment: However, I'm a beginner in SQL and was hoping if you could answer a few questions regarding my code: Firstly, for creating the new table, this is what I initially tried: `create table randtable as (select rowid from reviews_table order by random())`. This however threw a syntax error. Removing the parenthesis around the `select` subquery fixed the issue. Could you tell me why the first query didn't work?

Comment: Secondly, for selecting the rows, I initially tried without using a join, with the following code: `select * from reviews_table where rowid in (select rowid from randtable limit m offset n)`. But I observed that on varying the offset values in this code, certain rows which were supposed to be in the offset were also showing up. But isn't this query equivalent to `select * from reviews_table
as revt join randtable as rt on revt.rowid = rt.rowid limit m offset n`(in which the offsets worked fine)?